# Compiling Default Vaadin Widgets of a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, widget, vaadin

I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't seem to find an the exact response that I've been looking for. So I'm in the middle of altering a web application that once relied heavily on the jQuery UI to use Vaadin, instead. To make it easy for me to understand, I created a new Maven project and altered the `pom.xml` to include the following plugins:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <server>local_tomcat</server>
        <path>/illuminate</path>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
    </configuration>
    <version>1.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Now, I can manage to build and deploy my very simple application to Tomcat just fine, but when I attempt to go to it, I get the following error:

[image: Failed to load the widgetset]

In order to get a better understanding of how to set up this kind of project, I checked out a recent applicaiton that uses Vaadin with Maven from our repository called "Tag." Looking at the error, it looks as though it's trying to find a JavaScript file `nocache.js` in a directory that starts off accurate (Illuminate is my current application), but then branches off into this other project that has no link to my current one. I'm not sure if the browser has something to do with this or not, but I learned that it might have something to do with the widgets of my project having not been compiled yet. I've noticed that there are some other plugins that will do this, but these two are the only ones that this other project, Tag, makes use of, so I figured mine should work just fine. I have also been trying to follow the step-by-step process to make a simple "Hello World" like program from the Vaadin Tutorial. So... Anyone know what I am missing? If it's the compilation of the widgets (I only wish to use the defaults, I suppose), do I NEED those other plugins?

Comment: Which widgetset do you have set in your web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats problem of tomcat not deploying VAADIN dir content.

see below blog

http://fmucar.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/vaadin-maven2-eclipse/

Comment: Those steps worked quite well and used far less gibberish that the project I've been trying to mimic; thanks!